# Google Cloud: No DNS records

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've setup my Google Cloud and I've put the DNS Servers they provide in my URL seller panel.

However, testing my site from other devices, results in this error:

[image]

But when trying my site on internet from my PC o Laptop I can access that URL:

```
http://stickersgallito.pe/stickers/stickers-troquelados/subir-arte
```

Correctly.

[image]

**Google Cloud - Cloud DNS**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That link works for me on both browser (Chrome) and phone (Pixel).  A DNS lookup from a 3rd party tool also correctly finds the domain [https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=http%3a%2f%2fstickersgallito.pe&run=toolpage](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=http%3A%2F%2Fstickersgallito.pe&run=toolpage)

I think the problem was that your mobile provider caches web results and DNS and it's cache was stale.  You can see this in the error message you received - "Your cache administrator is webmaster@wayport.net".

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check your Domain Registrart Nameservers. It should be similar to your Nameservers on your Cloud DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the link and it is working fine.The only problem i can see here is your mobile provider is caching DNS which may take some time as you are using cloudflare service.